# Stop child li from being clickable but keep function of contained a

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a navigation that looks like this:

```
<ul class="first-ul">
    <li class="toggle-sub-menu"><a href="link1.html">1
        <ul class="second-ul">
            <li><a href="link2.html">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="link3.html">3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

My second ul is hidden and gets toggled with click on 'toggle-sub-menu':

```
$('.toggle-sub-menu').click(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(200)
});
```

Now, as I only want to hide the second-ul if the li with the class'toggle-sub-menu' is clicked, and not if any child like the children li or a I added

```
$('.toggle-sub-menu').click(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(200)
}).children().click(function(e) {
  return false;
});
```

This prevents the ul from hiding if a child is clicked, however, it makes the 'a' with href not clickable anymore.

I tried

```
$('.toggle-sub-menu').click(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(200)
}).children('ul').children('li').click(function(e) {
  return false;
});
```

However, the a tags are still not clickable. What can I do to make the li's not clickable but the a tags working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify it like this: Add class `list-element` to your lis

```
$('.toggle-sub-menu').click(function() {
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(200)
}).children('ul').children('li').click(function(e){
 if($(e.target).hasClass('list-element'))     
     return false;
});
```

This will not make anchor tags unclickable.

Comment: You code will not work due to the .click(function(e){ part in the second click function(syntax error).

Comment: Sorry that's a typo. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Now my only problem is, while the a works they also hide the ul on click - but I should be able to solve this myself.

Comment: @Yogita088 No problem.

Comment: maybe try with event.stopPropagation()?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning false, try to use

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: That does the same thing.

Comment: Then try to add style
    pointer-events: none;
to the children

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, however, @Yogita088 is right, this does not lead to the right result for me either - I also heard e.preventDefault() should not be used anymore, is this true?

Comment: @HyukchanKwon sadly I need an option that works in IE8, so pointer-events is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a need to a pure CSS solution.

```
li.toggle-sub-menu ul{
  display:block;
}

li.toggle-sub-menu.active ul{
  display:none;
}
```

This means when ever the `li` with the class `toggle-sub-menu` has a class `active` show the `ul` inside it, else keep it hidden. This way there is no issue in the click. Also this solution assumes your `li` gets a class active when ever its clicked and is active. If not, then you just have to add and remove the `active` classes to the li on click. let me know if you need further help

Comment: Thank you, but a css based solution is sadly not what I am looking for - thank you very much however for taking your time and trying to help me!

Comment: Since you had the OP tagged css I had to give my solution. And I do not understand how your accepted answer solves your issue :)

Comment: Oh I'm very sorry about the css tag, I had originally planned to include my css but then I realised it would add nothing to my question and removed it, but not the tag. The marked answer does indeed some my problem of making the inner li not clickable but it's child a.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code

```
.children().click(function(e) {
  return false;
})
```

sets the onclick of the children of toggle-sub-menu to be false. When onclick for an a-element returns false, this cancels the default action of clicking on it - thus making "not clickable".

If you want the links to still navigate the user when clicked, you should make sure their onclick-code returns true or somehow manually redirects the user. I.E. try writing

```
.children().click(function(e) {
  return true;
})
```